# Как сдвинуть скролл-бар по клику на изображение влево и вправо

Tags: javascript, jquery

В моем слайдере по клику на миниатюрные изображения скролл-бар прокручивается только в правую сторону. Я бы хотел добавить возможность прокручивания скролла и в левую сторону, но не представляю как это можно реализовать. 
Было бы проще добавить стрелки в слайдер и сделать их якорями, но этот вариант не подходит. 
Прилагаю мой скрипт который вызывает событие прокрутки:

```
function changeImage(event) {
event = event || window.event;
var targetElement = event.target || event.srcElement;

console.log(event);
var left = event.offsetX + 50;
var past = event.offsetX;

if (targetElement.tagName == 'IMG') {
    $('#main-img').fadeOut(200);
    setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementById('main-img').src = targetElement.getAttribute('src');
        $('#main-img').fadeIn(200);
    }, 150);

    var left = if(event.offsetX > past)
    {
        $('.dragscroll').animate({scrollLeft: '+=' + left}, 200);
    } else {
        $('.dragscroll').animate({scrollLeft: '-=' + left}, 200);
    }
}
```

}

[image: slider]

Answer (score 0):

Добавь промежуточное значение, какое хранит позицию прошлого ивента.

```
var past = event.offsetX; //1 img
```

и проверяй его координаты с текущем ивентом, соответственно добавляй или убавляй `50`

```
var left = if(event.offsetX > past)
{
    left = event.offsetX + 50
} else {
    left = event.offsetX - 50;
}
```

Comment: Проверьте строку `var left = if(event.offsetX> past)`

Comment: @AGS17, спасибо за подсказку, я понял логику, но наверное туплю в синтаксисе, консоль почему то ругается.